# Datagrid not showing data in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

I am new to Winforms and was just trying a Sample Application having 2 Forms.

- Form1 is having textbox, combobox , radiobutton and a submit button
- Form2 has a datagrid which is supposed to show the data sent by Form1.

**Form1**

```html
 DataFetch fetch ;
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            fetch = new DataFetch();
            comboBox1.DataSource = fetch.getDesignation();
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";

            radioButton1.Checked = true;
        }
        
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.Designation = comboBox1.SelectedText==""?"Admin":comboBox1.SelectedText;
            employee.IsCertified = radioButton1.Checked == true ? true : false;
            employee.name = textBox1.Text;
            Form2 form = new Form2(employee);
            form.Show();
        }
```

**Form2**

```html
 public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2(Employee employee)
        { 
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = employee;
        }
     }
```

**Form2 Designer Code**

```html
 partial class Form2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 93);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 150);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1);
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(460, 346);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.Text = "Form2";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    }
```

Though i am able to get Data in the constructor of Form2 yet i am not able to bind it to the grid on in this case show that to the grid.

Comment: Have you set `AutoGenerateColumns` for `dataGridView1` in designer? It would be better if you share designer for `dataGridView1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridView's` `DataSource` generally is a collection and I'm not sure why are you trying to bind a single object to it. But anyway, you can initialize a one-item List, then bind it to `datagridview1`'s datasource.

For example:

```
datagridview1.DataSource = new List<Employee> { employee };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can did that easily

all items of you want add in datatable and that send on Form 2 
and then bind it on gridview

ihtink it will help you